# Where is the "building a secure web site" question?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

There used to be a question on SO to the effect of "If even Jeff Atwood can make (insert some grave mistake here), what do I need to take into consideration when building a secure web site?"

I found that a very useful resource to point people to who ask about "how do I make xyz totally secure".

I would like to flag it for a historical lock, but it's no longer visible - the great weakness of the "let people who care about them make a case for undeletion" approach. But that's a different discussion.

Could someone point me to the right URL?

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794016/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-security

Comment: @Oleksi thanks, but nope - the one I'm thinking about had *even more* upvotes (like 700+) and was about web sites specifically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If [Jeff Atwood](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/37/jeff-atwood) can forget about [HttpOnly cookies](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html), [sitemaps](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001174.html), *and* [cross-site request forgeries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001171.html) *all in the same site*, what important thing could I be forgetting as well?

[What should every programmer know about web development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development) was migrated to Programmers.SE. It is still open.

Comment: Ah, cool! Thanks very much. (`you can accept an answer in 8 minutes...` by which time I'll be in bed. Tomorrow thne.)

Comment: FWIW, I still use this as an example of "the *right way* to do a wiki question on SE" (over 100 revisions to the top answer, the last just two days ago).

Comment: @Shog9 `22 revs, 18 users 47% naeblis`? either all revs got merged on the migration, or you exaggerated a little bit

Comment: @ajax333221: Yeah, revisions are discarded upon migration - there were 88 revisions to the answer on Stack Overflow.